# Python3 - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - List

Tags: python, list, append

I've just recently started exploring Python and can't seem to figure out a way to code this. I'm guessing the fix is fairly simple. Can someone help me?

```
temp = 0
for i in list[::-1]:
    temp = temp + 1.11
    list[i].append("{0:.2f}".format(temp))
```

Comment: Do **not** use `list` as a variable name. It shadows the built-in `list` function. A for-loop iterates over the *elements in the list*. If you want indices, use `range`. Whatever is in your list, at least one element is a `str`, snd you try to use that as an index, hence your error

Comment: iterator `i` is not the index in your context, its a `list` and you cannot use a list as an index for an other list, Also what is the desired output and input ?

Comment: Use the shorter temp += 1.11

Answer (score 0):

You already have the list item as `i` and you can just append to it. `list[i]` is indexing the list with the list item (which I think is another list) and not index.

So instead of

```
list[i].append("{0:.2f}".format(temp))
```

you should do

```
i.append("{0:.2f}".format(temp))
```